# why is the used +availabe space is less than the size of a filesystem

Tags: unix

Why is the total available space and used space less than the size of a filesystem.

Size Used Available Capacity 
 5.5T 4.2T 1.2T 78% /u03

Here I see a discrepancy of 100G in the filesystem. Could you let me know why is this happening and where is the 100 G consumed?

Comment: Couldn't it just be that you for example have 4.24TB used (rounded to 4.2), 1.24TB free (rounded to 1.2) and 5.48TB (rounded to 5.5) total?

Comment: okay thanks but the thing is after getting 500G added to the filesystem. It is as follows

Size Used Available Capacity 5.9T 4.3T 1.6T 73% /u03. So I am curious out here where did the 100 G go?

Comment: if we add 500G and assume the above case then that has to be 6T right.Please let me know on this.

Comment: Depends how you measure the 500G, is it the disk size or the actual space after the file system has been created with its overhead?

Comment: This is after the addition of luns to the existing disk. Could you also elaborate on what you exactly mean here by telling " Depends how you measure the 500G"

Comment: Off-topic for StackOverfow, which is dedicated to helping with programming code problems. More appropriate to https://superuser.com . Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.